# split string using a given unicode sequence as delimiter and keep the delimeter

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

This could be a possible duplicate but I tried many answers available from here but none worked for my requirement.

I want to split the String = "क्षत्रिय" into ["क्ष", "त्र", "ि", "य"] using a listOf("श्र","क्ष","त्र","ज्ञ") delimiters and want to keep them into result array as above.
Note that the श्र, क्ष, त्र, ज्ञ themselves are made of a group of characters so are Strings but not characters.

Comment: Add the code you tried please.

Comment: Look up 'positive lookahead'. If you want `split()` to remove no characters at all, call `.split("(?=pattern here)` - that's positive lookahead.

Comment: Match something like `[^रषत्रज्ञ]+|[रषत्रज्ञ]+` but I don't know Hindi or how that works with regular expressions.

Comment: I can make it split to `[क्ष, त्र, िय]` using a straightforward apporach - are you sure the split should be `["क्ष", "त्र", "ि", "य"]`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland there are few compound characters in Hindi e.g. `श्र=श+्+र, क्ष=क+्+ष, त्र=त+्+र, ज्ञ=ज+्+ञ` , though for the regex @Bohemian 's answer helped me, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using only the delimiters given as a look behind, splits to what you want
except the the last element:

```
String str = "क्षत्रिय";
List<String> delims = List.of("श्र","क्ष","त्र","ज्ञ");
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=(" + String.join("|", delims) + "))");
```

Output:

```
[क्ष, त्र, िय]
```

---

To split exactly to your desire, I has to add an alternate split on the last character:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=(" + String.join("|", delims) + "))|(?=.$)");
```

Output:

```
[क्ष, त्र, ि, य]
```

Comment: Thanks, eventually your single line regex helped me (+1), but the problem lied in using direct regex literal in split method `str.split("<regex>")` in case of kotlin. Using the `str.split(Pattern.compose("<regex>"))` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the Java vs Kotlin issue (since the answers I was following were from Java considering both are interoperable), but the root problem lied in the direct string literal used in the split method in case of kotlin.

The below code doesn't work:

```
val array = "क्षत्रिय".split("(?<=(श्र|क्ष|त्र|ज्ञ))|(?=.\$)")
println(array)

Answer: [क्षत्रिय] // no split
```

But using `Pattern.compile(<string_regex>)` as below worked:

```
val array = "क्षत्रिय".split(Pattern.compile("(?<=(श्र|क्ष|त्र|ज्ञ))|(?=.\$)"))
println(array)

Answer: [क्ष, त्र, ि, य] // splits as expected
```

The differences between these two code in AndroidStudio:

[image: split with regex literal]
[image: split with Pattern]

The single line regex is followed from the [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian)'s answer to this question.